# update tabela com foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer update em uma tabela com chaves estrangeiras, justamente nas chaves estrangeiras quero deixá-las com valor `NULL` ao fazer update mas não estou conseguindo esta é minha query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE agenda SET id_pessoa=:id_pessoa ,id_tp_pessoa=:id_tp_pessoa ';
$sql .= 'WHERE id_agenda = :id_agenda';

$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(':id_pessoa', $id_pessoa);

$stm->bindValue(':id_tp_pessoa', $id_tp_pessoa);


$stm->bindValue(':id_agenda', $id_agenda);
$retorno = $stm->execute();
```

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Não está conseguindo porquê? Algum erro?

Comment: Pode ser que algum campo não aceita nulo no banco, impedindo então o seu update.

Comment: Sergio, sua pergunta está incompleta. O que exatamente acontece? Mensagens de erro?

Comment: desculpe demora .   erro tava no banco nao estava setado  NULL.  falha minha  sorry :(